# Backbone - Render client views then create them on save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have absolutely no idea how to get this to work. I can create the models, but then I can't run create or anything on them afterwards. I've been at this for 6 hours already... Please tell me where I'm going wrong :(!

1) Create a WorkflowCollection `this.workflows = new WorkflowCollection();` `workflows.length = 0`.

2) Add empty workflows for each of the workflow ids (`var workflow = [1,2,3]`):

```
for(var i =0;i<workflow.length;i++;) { 
       this.workflows.add(new Workflow({fk_workflow_id: workflow[i]})); 
}
```

3) `workflows.length = 3`. Render the views for the current workflows:

```
var self = this; 
this.workflows.each(function(model) {
       self.renderView(model.get("fk_workflow_id"), model);
});
```

renderView for example, calls a function:

```
if(this.kit) this.kit.close();
        this.kit = new Workflow.PostageView({
            model: model
        // posView may change el? check later
        });
```

4) Fetch the new data to update the view's models. DOESN'T WORK.

```
this.workflows.fetch({
    success: function () {
        self.workflows.each(function (model) {
            self.renderView(model.get("fk_workflow_id"), model);
        });
    }
});
```

5. Attempt to save a model: 
`FileApp.workflowRouter.pos.create is not a function`

How come it can't access create?! Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/8upZK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. After 6 hours, it was because I should have been using the COLLECTION to create/update, rather than the view. I don't know why I chose the view  (step 5).

I.E. FileApp.workflowRouter.workflows.create(). Create/Add to a COLLECTION, not a view. Fuubar.